# Настройки log4j. Блокировка стандартного логгера

Tags: java, log4j

Здравствуйте, уважаемые.

Взялся изучать `log4j`, сразу напоролся на вилы.

Почему не блокируется стандартный логгер? Где нормальный вывод?

Настройки:

```
log4j.debug = false
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, file, stdout
log4j.appender.stdout = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.encoding = UTF-8
log4j.appender.stdout.target = System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout = org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.conversionPattern = %d{ISO8601} [%-5p] - %m [Thread:%t][%20c{-1}]%n
log4j.appender.file = org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.encoding = UTF-8
log4j.appender.file.file = log.txt
log4j.appender.file.file.MaxBackupIndex = 10
log4j.appender.file.file.MaxFileSize = 100MB
log4j.appender.file.layout = org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.conversionPattern = %d{ISO8601} [%-5p] - %m [Thread:%t][%20c{-1}]%n
```

Судя по настройкам - лог должен вестись только с уровня WARNING. Однако, в System.err вылетает следующее:

```
июн 05, 2013 2:30:36 PM auserver.gameserver.IdFactory <init>
INFO: IdFactory: 102912 id's available.
июн 05, 2013 2:30:36 PM auserver.gameserver.GameTimeController <init>
INFO: GameTimeController started.
июн 05, 2013 2:30:36 PM auserver.gameserver._Gameserver <init>
INFO: AU server: Started, free memory 241 Mb of 247 Mb
```

Файл log.txt создается, но пустой. Если уровень поднять до INFO  - то в файл улетает (инициализируется mchange):

```
2013-06-05 13:59:55,789 [INFO ] - MLog clients using log4j logging.[Thread:main][ mchange.v2.log.MLog]
2013-06-05 13:59:56,101 [INFO ] - Initializing c3p0-0.9.2-pre4 [built 16-June-2012 20:16:37 -0400; debug? true; trace: 10][Thread:main][mchange.v2.c3p0.C3P0Registry]
2013-06-05 13:59:56,273 [INFO ] - Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ acquireIncrement -> 5, acquireRetryAttempts -> 0, acquireRetryDelay -> 500, autoCommitOnClose -> true, automaticTestTable -> connection_test_table, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, dataSourceName -> 1hge0yi8v5hk8h71otv3mo|6f3ea, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, description -> null, driverClass -> com.mysql.jdbc.Driver, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, identityToken -> 1hge0yi8v5hk8h71otv3mo|6f3ea, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 3600, initialPoolSize -> 10, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:mysql://localhost/auserver, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 0, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 50, maxStatements -> 0, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 100, minPoolSize -> 10, numHelperThreads -> 3, preferredTestQuery -> null, properties -> {user=******, password=******}, propertyCycle -> 0, statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false ][Thread:main][mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource]
```

Comment: [посмотрите это][1]


  [1]: http://www.skipy.ru/useful/logging.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Однако, в System.err вылетает
> следующее:

Если вы не ошибаетесь, то в системе зарегистрирован еще какой-то аппендер, который выводит на `System.err` - ибо по вашей конфигурации вы выводите все консоль (`System.out`) и в файл `log.txt`

Второе соображение: такое ощущение что к вам валятся логи от сторонней библиотеки на что указывает аппендер `auserver.gameserver.IdFactory` - вполне вероятно, что у этой либы своя конфигурация и вы не влияете на нее.

Comment: Нашел я причину своих бед... У меня в импортах был остандартный логгер указан, но не везде.

PS: auserver.gameserver.IdFactory - это не либа.

Comment: Ну я же говорил - чудес не бывает, не зря мне показалось что логи на `System.err` другого формата - не вашего.